# Creating a Heatmap / Heatmaply in R for yearly data

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap, heatmaply

Follow up Heatmap question [Creating a heatmap / ordering columns for yearly data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786215/creating-a-heatmap-ordering-columns-for-yearly-data-in-r?noredirect=1#comment76596384_44786215)

[Heatmaply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Zax.jpg)

[Heatmaply2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIaoY.png)

1. The rownames change but my data does not change with this, can I ask for any help on how to have each respective row of data move with it's name?
2. Is there an easier way to make the graph / png wider as I have been messing around with the margins and all I seem to do is make it narrower.
3. I've attached a second image to show when I highlight a particular cell e.g. Skin Diseases in Jan a different value to what is in the .csv file, is this right? (Seeing as the colors match up should I just run with it?)

   library(heatmaply)
       x <-read.csv("Heatmap.csv", check.names = FALSE)

   ```
   rownames(x) <- c('All Others', 'Circulatory Diseases', 'Digestive Diseases', 'Ear Diseases', 'Endocrine/Metabolic','Eye Diseases', 'Genitourinary Diseases', 'Ill-defined Condition', 'Infectious & Parasitic', 'Injury/ Poisoning', 'Mental & Behavioural', 'Musculoskeletal', 'Neoplasms', 'Nervous System', 'Pregnancy/Childbirth', 'Respiratory', 'Skin Diseases')

   x <- x[,2:13, drop=FALSE]
   x <- as.matrix(scale(x))

   heatmaply(x,colors = heat.colors(200), k_col =1, k_row = 2, dendrogram = FALSE, margins = c(100, 160), 
         scale_fill_gradient_fun = ggplot2::scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", midpoint = 50, limits = c(0, 100)))
   ```

Comment: It's best to ask one question at a time because you an accept at most one answer. Also, make sure your post is self contained and includes a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please follow @MrFlick so that people could answer your question.